# How To Port Forward To Machine on the LAN?

Tags: port-forwarding, lan, wan

Win10.  I can port forward to my IP cameras because they have a Port number.

10.0.0.97:97  for instance is one of them.

I forward WAN port 97 to LAN port 97.  Job done.

But how do I forward to a machine on the LAN?  they have no port numbers, do they?

When I input our IP on a machine outside the LAN I only get the router.

When I try to use the port forwarding routine it wants two Port numbers: WAN and LAN.

?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a http service (also known as a webserver) that runs inside your LAN and you want to show it on a public IP (which you call WAN IP).

http runs by default on port 80. That is if you write http://example.com you are really saying http://example.com:80

It seems your router already serves its own http on WAN port 80. You could for example try LAN IP, LAN port 80 forwarded from WAN IP, WAN port 14876.

Outside of your LAN try http://example.com:14876 (I used a random port number).

Important security notes: A public webserver should be securely configured and regularly patched otherwise you will quickly get hacked and become a spambot. Therefore your router really really isn't qualified to be a webserver. I mean it shouldn't show any setup pages to public internet, even the password secured ones.